# Backbone collection could save bulk of model through passing in url array of object

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, dropwizard, backbone.js-collections

I have written Post API that can accept Array of objects like `[{"name":"ABC","city":"Banglo"},{"name":"AC","city":"Newyork"},{"name":"C","city":"Mumbai"}]` in Java using the Dropwizard framework.

Now I'm trying to call these API method through Backbone Collection create function.Ist i knew that create accept only one object at time like `collection.create({"name":"ABC","city":"Banglore"})`.Suppose if I passed array of objects in create then it parsed as `{"0":{"name":"ABC","city":"Banglor"},"1":{"name":"AC","city":"Newyork"},"2":{"name":"C","city":"Mumbai"}}`.
But Java API could not accept key value pair objects.So How can i call those API method from backbone collection.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, `create` accepts properties for a single model. You may want to just use [`add`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add) instead, which accepts an array of models or objects containing properties (if a model property is defined in the collection). Then, call the [`sync`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-sync) method to add pass those to your API.